# How to get HTML inbetween divs with JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do get HTML between divs with JQuery or javascript or is this impossible?

```
<div>
   not this text
</div>

but this text

<div>
   not this text
</div>
```

Comment: a lot but nothing usefull, why would i get a downvote btw?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but this is a poorly written question. You should as @AndrewMarshall asked, tell us what you tried. But also, you should tell us why you have to do this. The obvious answer is to put a `div` where you want it in the HTML and write what you want to it. By giving us background, someone may suggest a different solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, honestly I had no intention to do anything with it I just wanted to know if its possible and how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted markup you can try the following.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].nextSibling;
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gLUc/

Or if you want to select specific div elements:

```
var elem = $('#aParent div:first').get(0).nextSibling;
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

Comment: In IE 8, the jsFiddle example displays `undefined`. It does work in Chrome.

Comment: @Karl That's because of `trim` method that IE8 doesn't support it. Try it without the `trim` method.

Comment: Could you also do a jfiddle example on the second piece of code?